# How to make edittext scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I'm gonna make a texteditor, but there's a problem, it can not scroll smoothly especially when theres big text in it. I have overridedden the oninterceptTouchEvent and ignored some actions, but it doesn't work

Comment: also i tried the android:scrollbars and setScroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
editText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
editText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

(assuming your EditText's editText)

Comment: Thanks, but it cannot scroll through all the text, just a part of the text.

Comment: Try 'android:gravity = "fill_vertical"' or 'android:gravity = "center_vertical"' in layout file