# How to accelerate smooth scrolling in Android multiline Edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext, smooth-scrolling

Here is the `xml` (`activity_matches.xml`) that displays the output in the screen shot below in an `EditText` object named `txaMatches`:

```
<EditText
    android:id=                     "@+id/txaMatches"
    android:text=                   ""

    android:scrollbars=             "vertical"
    android:layout_below=           "@+id/pattern"
    android:textColor=              "@color/yellow_foreground"
    android:textSize=               "@dimen/matches_text"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"

    android:layout_width=           "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height=          "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd=  "true"
    tools:ignore=                   "LabelFor"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/matches_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/matches_padding"
    />
```

[image]

I would like the contents of this `multiline` `EditText` object to scroll smoothly with acceleration if the user swipes inside it.

Here's how I fill `txaMatches` (using `doInBackground`). This is the only place in Java code that I refer to it (of course I also define and initialize it in Java):

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < progress.length; i++)
    if(progress[i].length() > 1) MatchesActivity.txaMatches.append("\n" + progress[i]);
    else                         MatchesActivity.showLetter("Reading " + progress[i].charAt(0));
}
```

Is this an easy change to be made in `xml`?

Should I be using a `ListView`? Should the `EditText` be inside a `ListView`?

Am I going to have to write some Java code?

Given the small amount of code I've provided, I don't expect many details. Just an overview of what to Google would be a good start.

Comment: You have some related questions and answers to see: [java workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304118/how-to-make-edittext-scrolling-smoothly), [webview workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5594713/2668136) and maybe [xml workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193482/android-enabling-scrolling-on-edittext).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy (thanks to Fllo's [THIRD link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193561/2737933)). (The first was no help; the second focuses on Java code and the `ScrollView` class and is more involved than the third, which focuses on `xml` and was perfect for my situation (and required only changing the type of `txaMatches` to `TextView`):

start of new code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd=  "true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

end of new code except for closing tag

```
<TextView
    android:id=                     "@+id/txaMatches"
    android:scrollbars=             "vertical"
    android:layout_width=           "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height=          "wrap_content"
    />
</ScrollView>
```